# Mapping and accessing all terminals in a LAN

Tags: networking

How do I find out the ip of all the terminals connected to my lan and run a script file in all the terminals simultaneously. I'm aware of the common user name and password of all the terminals. And I'm not a sudo user. Basically I want to SSH into all terminals and run a script automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need a public/private keypair for this approach or you'll be forced to enter the password for every host/ip.
I'd use nmap and read the xml output for open ports. I'm too lazy to research the code for this part. If you've got the ip addresses you can remote execute your local script in a loop.

```
for ip in ips; do
  ssh user@$ip 'bash -s' < local_script.sh
done
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use caution that you're not trying to accomplish something nefarious with this question.

**Finding the computers**

1) If your computer has been connected to the network for a while, you can do an *arp* command. Read the man page with `man arp` Example:

`arp -a`

2) You can ping the broadcast address and see which machines reply. Keep in mind that this only works if the machine is online and is also not previously configured to ignore ping traffic. Usually the broadcast ends with .255. Find your address with *ifconfig* and then ping the broadcast.

```
ifconfig
ping x.x.x.255
```

**Running the Script**

The real problem is the script. If you're an admin, you should already have this access. You must be a user on each machine that you want to execute the script on. That means that you must have your own account with proper credentials or you need to have a legitimate admin account on each machine, for service and maintenance. Provided that you've already written the script, you could then deploy it to all of your terminals and execute.

Comment: But arp gives only the It's of those machines I have already communicated right?  Moreover I have an account in every machine and I can manually SSH into each of them and run the script. What I'm looking for is a automatic way to to it.

Comment: If you do have access, it seems that you would want to generate some keys for each machine to permit password-less authentication. At that point, you could have a script roll through ssh connections and execute what you needed. The script itself will do things sequentially, just like you or I would, but it will do it much faster and automatically reach every machine on your network.  Here is a reference link for [generating a key:] (http://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password)